# Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravelcollective

i currently installed laravel and trying to create my first app, however when i required the laravel collective i get error above.

here is my composer.json

```
{
 "require": {
    "laravel/installer": "~1.1",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
 }
}
```

and my app.php have these lines..
providers=>

```
 ...Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

aliases=>

```
 ...'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    'Form'      => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html'      => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

i've been reading and searching for solutions but currently they never worked for me.. any help will be appreciated.. thanks in advance..

**UPDATE**
this is my cmd as of now..
[image]

Comment: What steps did you follow to install `laravelcollective`?

Comment: @james i followed the documentation here http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html

Comment: So you definitely ran `composer update` after adding that line to your `composer.json`?

Comment: yup, i also tried different version like ~5.0, 5.1.*, then make a composer update after editing the composer.json.

Answer (score 1):

u have to use php artisan serve inside your project folder. not inside composer folder.
for eg, laravel is my project folder inside www directory,
so, f:/wamp/www/laravel> php artisan serve

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I took to install it in my app in Laravel 5.1.

I would suggest you delete the vendor folder for this from your vendor files and remove that line from your `composer.json file` to start from scratch.

First, require the package:

```
composer require "illuminate/html":"5.0.*"
```

Next, add it to your providers:

```
'providers' => [
    ...

    'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
],
```

Finally, add it to your aliases:

```
'aliases' => [

    ...

    'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade', 
    'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
],
```

You can check to see if it has worked by doing the following:

1) `php artisan tinker`

2) `> Form::text('foo')`

Which should output `"<input name=\"foo\" type=\"text\">"`

Comment: but i read that Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider is not a core element anymore and should use laravelcollective instead.. is that wrong?

Comment: If you are requiring the package and follow those steps it will work fine. But you are correct that it is not a core package anymore. Which is why we are requiring it.

Comment: Those are the steps I have taken on multiple Laravel 5.1 apps I have built and it always works 100%

Comment: this is what i did, remove the vendor folder, updated the composer.json file with only "laravel/installer": "~1.1", and ran composer update, after that created my app, and did your instructions, however now im recieving Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found, :(

Comment: Did you remove the classes from `app.php` when you were removing everything?

Comment: It sounds like an installation issue.

Comment: if that's the case, i think i need to restart from scratch.. thanks for your help and patience @James really appreciated it.

Comment: No harm in doing so with a fresh installation. Follow those steps and you should be good as gold. Note, this method uses the `composer require` command and so that will add it to your `composer.json` for you so that you do not need to. If it works then please upvote/accept as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have installed the HTML package and you are trying to use it in your "old" laravel app.

If you install a new app using the composer it should work fine, but if you are trying to use it in your "old" app that you created before installing the form/html collective try to download [the files](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html) and copy the files in the `src` folder to the `config` folder in your app and you are good to go.